# Mitel Connect Softphone will not play call audio through headphones

Tags: windows-10, audio, earbuds, softphone

I'm hoping someone out there is a mitel guru and can help me figure out why Call audio will not play through the user's headphones (ear buds). This is a really strange one. I have verified that the earbuds and headphone jack are working outside of call audio, in fact if the earbuds are plugged in, you can even hear the phone ring through the headphones, but when the call is answered, the call audio will only play through the laptop speakers other things play through the earbuds fine. I have verified the headphones are selected as the default play back device. System is running Win-10 1909.

I have checked the sound settings and nothing seems to be out of place. I also tried disabling the main speakers to try to force all audio to the earbuds, but when I tried that as a solution, the audio did not play at all. I was thinking maybe it was a driver issue but testing on my own laptop has (different make model and audio driver) resulted in the same problem. Any Mitel gurus out there who know about this and how to resolve?

Comment: Please provide the mitel soft phone full software name & version. 1)Do you know anyone who has actually used headphones successfully with the mitel soft phone? 1a)If so what Windows version where they using? 2)is there is newer version of the mitel soft phone SW? 3)have you tried contacting mitel?

Comment: Do the earbuds contain a microphone (a headset)? User guide seems to imply that may be required so it might not be possible to use just headphones & a different microphone (ex: built into laptop or USB mic/webcam)

Comment: Reading the answer below these are just standard earbuds with mic plugged into the PC 3.5 mm headphone/mic combo jack. I'm thinking something this simplistic may not be supported for call audio. To answer the previous, afaik only one person has been successful, but using the same headphones. settings are the same for both softphone clients and server side. Connect software has a newer version, but only works with cloud solutions not internal servers (major oversight IMO).

Comment: Not adding this as an answer, since a) you wrote you've tried this already and b) I'm not sure if it's the same product, but on MiCollab Client I've had success by disabling the unwanted devices in Windows settings. It took a moment for the client to pick that up, though. [The manual](https://www.mitel.com/document-center/applications/collaboration/micollab/micollab-client/95/en/micollab-for-pc-client-end-user-online-help) talks about setting a "preferred audio device" in Windows, but that doesn't work for me; the client seems to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

[Mitel Connect SW v19.2 SP1 User Guide pg28](https://www.mitel.com/document-center/business-phone-systems/mivoice-connect/connect-client) says:

> Customizing the Softphone:
>
> 1. On the Dashboard, click the  tab.
> 2. On the second pane, click .
> 3. Click the Softphone tab to display the softphone options. Note: If you do not see the Softphone tab, contact your Connect administrator.
> 4. To switch to a different audio device, in the Capture audio through field, click the drop-down list, and select the preferred
>    audio device.** Note: If required, plug your audio device into the
>    computer’s headset port or use the computer’s built- in speakers.
> 5. Select On startup assign me to my softphone to handle calls and voicemails on the softphone from the time you first log in to the
>    client.
> 6. Select Enable auto gain control to enable the automatic control. Note: The Connect client softphone supports a variety of Plantronics
>    and Jabra headsets. For details, search the Mitel knowledgebase at the
>    following location:
>
> - For Customers:
>   https://mitelcommunity.force.com/customer/s

Comment: I'm on a cell phone so editing is crap, I can fix later or someone else feel free to edit :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I was able to fix it by clicking my name/profile picture in Mitel Connect. In the window that appears there is a drop down box under softphone. I changed that from default to communications. In Windows I set my head phones as the default communication device under the Playback tab of the Sound Control Panel.

Comment: Wow Took me for ever to respond to this. Sorry About that. I can confirm that this is the case, however for me, I still was unable to hear anything from the caller. this actually broke the soft phone from being able to play sound at all... I recently found out that our software is (very very very) out of date and will be reaching out to our voip partner to update. It will likely work after that. Thanks for your reply!!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. Our issues appear to have been related to out of date software from 2018. Upgrading the application and server to the latest versions has allowed the use of earbuds from the mic-headphone combo jack. This was not a selectable option before, but has been added in.